# How to fold/reduce a map?

Tags: fp-ts

I want to be able to fold/reduce a Map, just like I can with Array and Set. The closest I see is something called `getFoldableWithIndex` but I don't know how to use it or get it to compile with Typescript. One thing I find annoying is that it requires an ORD. Maybe this is required to make the function more deterministic but sorting is not important for many folding/reducing tasks and decreases performance. My workaround is leaving fp-ts, generating an array or iterable of [key,value] pairs, and doing a simple reduce on it to find the person with the max age.

```
import { map as MAP, ord as ORD } from "fp-ts"

type Person = string;
type Age = number;

const oldestPerson = (ps:Map<Person, Age>) =>
  pipe(ps, MAP.getFoldableWithIndex<Person>(ORD.fromCompare<Person>((a,b)=>0)))......
```

---

Just noticed a more recent unreleased version has support for reduce. Still don't know why ORD is required or how to use getFolderableWithIndex or when the newer version will be released.

https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/2.11/src/ReadonlyMap.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to stay "within `fp-ts`" you could do something like the following:

```js
import { flow, pipe, tuple } from "fp-ts/function"
import * as Mn from "fp-ts/Monoid"
import * as N from "fp-ts/number"
import * as O from "fp-ts/Option"
import * as Ord from "fp-ts/Ord"
import * as RM from "fp-ts/ReadonlyMap"
import * as RT from "fp-ts/ReadonlyTuple"
import * as Sg from "fp-ts/Semigroup"
import * as S from "fp-ts/string"

type Person = string
type Age = number
type PersonAge = readonly [Person, Age]

const ordByAge: Ord.Ord<PersonAge> = pipe(N.Ord, Ord.contramap(RT.snd))

const monoidMaxByAge: Mn.Monoid<O.Option<PersonAge>> = pipe(
  ordByAge,
  Sg.max,
  O.getMonoid
)

const oldestPerson = (ps: ReadonlyMap<Person, Age>) =>
  pipe(
    ps,
    RM.foldMapWithIndex(S.Ord)(monoidMaxByAge)(flow(tuple, O.some)),
    O.map(RT.fst)
  )
```

Which is pretty verbose and doesn't address your concern about performance.

> One thing I find annoying is that it requires an ORD. Maybe this is required to make the function more deterministic but sorting is not important for many folding/reducing tasks and decreases performance.

You're right that it's about determinism. The native JS `Map` stores entries in insertion order, so without an `Ord` instance for the keys, this `oldestPerson` function could yield different results for two given `Map`s that are equivalent aside from insertion order. I would think of that as unexpected behavior.

Here's what I would expect to hold:

```js
import * as assert from "assert"

const aliceBob: ReadonlyMap<Person, Age> = new Map([
  ["Alice", 25],
  ["Bob", 25],
])

const bobAlice: ReadonlyMap<Person, Age> = new Map([
  ["Bob", 25],
  ["Alice", 25],
])

const emptyMap: ReadonlyMap<Person, Age> = new Map([])

assert.deepStrictEqual(oldestPerson(aliceBob), oldestPerson(bobAlice))
assert.deepStrictEqual(oldestPerson(emptyMap), O.none)
```

I agree that a lot of the functions in `fp-ts/ReadonlyMap` aren't very efficient, I think they're just meant to be a minimal "functional API" wrapper around a native data structure that doesn't play well with immutability and determinism. If performance is more of a concern I would probably do as you did and use the native methods.

> something called `getFoldableWithIndex` but I don't know how to use it or get it to compile with Typescript.

`getFoldableWithIndex` will return a `FoldableWithIndex` type class instance which isn't going to be useful to you here. This is a *value* that you would pass as an argument to a function that expects a `FoldableWithIndex` instance, which I'm not even sure there's a good example of one . There's a [`traverse_`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/5a80970678bdbcb31756cdfb8770a3fdc32a0434/src/Foldable.ts#L296) in `fp-ts/Foldable` which takes a `Foldable` instance, but no corresponding `traverseWithIndex_`, though that hypothetical function *would* take a `FoldableWithIndex` instance. There are [some](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/5a80970678bdbcb31756cdfb8770a3fdc32a0434/src/FoldableWithIndex.ts#L119) [functions](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/5a80970678bdbcb31756cdfb8770a3fdc32a0434/src/FoldableWithIndex.ts#L141) in `fp-ts/FoldableWithIndex`, but those are about *composing* two `FoldableWithIndex` instances into another (which is not useful here).

You could use that `FoldableWithIndex` directly: the type class instance is an object with an *uncurried* `foldMapWithIndex` method on it, so if you wanted to make the original snippet *even more verbose*, you could do:

```js
const oldestPerson = (ps: ReadonlyMap<Person, Age>) =>
  pipe(
    RM.getFoldableWithIndex(S.Ord).foldMapWithIndex(monoidMaxByAge)(
      ps,
      flow(tuple, O.some)
    ),
    O.map(RT.fst)
  )
```

but those instances aren't really meant to be used directly in a `pipe`, which is why I'd use the top-level `RM.foldMapWithIndex`. There's more about how type classes in `fp-ts` work [here](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/HKT.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```js
import { ordNumber } from 'fp-ts/Ord'

type Name = string
type Age = number
type Persons = Map<Name, Age>
const persons: Persons = new Map()

persons.set('Joao', 13)
persons.set('Roberto', 20)

const sorted = new Map(
  [...persons.entries()].sort((a, b) => ordNumber.compare(b[1], a[1]))
)
```

However, it is important to note that in this example, you are mutating the `persons` variable by calling `.set`.

A more pure, functional approach would be:

```js
import { ordNumber } from 'fp-ts/Ord'
import { Eq as StringEq } from 'fp-ts/string'
import * as F from 'fp-ts/function'
import * as M from 'fp-ts/Map'

type Name = string
type Age = number
const insertIntoPersons = M.upsertAt(StringEq)

const persons = F.pipe(
  new Map<Name, Age>(),
  insertIntoPersons('Joao', 13),
  insertIntoPersons('Roberto', 20)
)

const sorted = new Map(
  [...persons.entries()].sort((a, b) => ordNumber.compare(b[1], a[1]))
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this using fp-ts. It has an Array.reduce and I'm looking for something similar with Set and Map.

Comment: @JustinM mmm, not that I know of, no. but I guess you can convert the `Map` to an `Array` and call a reduce from there? what's your end goal?

Comment: In this case to do an efficient reduce/fold on Map and Set. To find the max, you don't need to sort - just loop through and keep track of the max. I find it odd that fp-ts doesn't allow this, especially with functions like "getFoldableWithIndex" and "toUnfoldable" where the docs make it sound almost like what I want. I'd really like to understand how fp-ts works, not just get the code written.

Comment: This kind of works... pipe(ps, MAP.toUnfoldable(ordString, ARRAY.Unfoldable)). It creates an array of [key,value] tuples. Still requires an unnecessary sort. Might as well break out of fp-ts to avoid the sort.

Comment: actually, fp-ts allows you to fold a `Map` using `getFoldableWithIndex` as you mentioned, as along as you provide a `Ord` instance for the keys... which is odd. you can check the code here: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Map.ts#L662

i honestly don't know why is that. i guess you can copy the `reduceWithIndex` function and modify it to get the keys unsorted, unless there is a reason for them to be sorted I don't know of

Comment: I couldn’t figure out how to use getFoldableWithIndex. Do you know how with my simple example?

Comment: can't paste code here I guess,  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235100/fp-ts-map